# jQuery - access multidimesional array from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I am sending some data with ajax, and as a response i get multidimensional array.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/slideshow/list.php",
            data: imageId,
            success: function(data){
                imagesList = data;
                console.log(imagesList);
                curentImage = imagesList[0];
            }
        });
```

Response, `data` looks like this. This is what i get on `console.log(imagesList)`:
I am using php, and the response is provided like this `<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>`

```
[
   [1,487124,"<img src=\"http:\/\/example.com\/images\/1\/487124.jpg\" \/>","http:\/\/example.com\/photos\/salle-a-manger---mineral\/649518","Title 1"],
   [2,732924,"<img src=\"http:\/\/example.com\/images\/1\/732924.jpg\"\/>","http:\/\/example.com\/photos\/salle-a-manger---","Title 2"],
   [3,341649,"<img src=\"http:\/\/example.com\/images\/2\/341649.jpg\"\/>","http:\/\/example.com\/photos\/salle-a-manger---","Title 3"]
]
```

If i try to access the first array with `imagesList[0]` it only shows `[`

How can i access the first or second array, or values inside of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the `dataType` in ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/slideshow/list.php",
            data: imageId,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                 $.each(data,function(key,value){
                       console.log('key:'+key+", value:"+value);
                       //do your stuff 
                 });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: can you please add more detail?